# 'Prepare segue' execute 'observe' only after the data are passed to the other view controller

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I want to share a struct (`Utente`) between two controllers using a segue, so I have written this code. The problem is that the `ref.observe` part is executed only after that the variable `ut` is passed to the other view. More precisely all the instructions are executed in the right order, at some point Xcode jump to the `let chatsingola = segue.destination as! ChatSingola; chatsingola.aaa = ut` instructions and pass the data to the other view controller, and after it redo all the instructions, with also the `ref.observe`.
Why it works like that? How can I solve this problem?

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{

        let selectedRow = indexPath.row
        let msg = Messaggi[selectedRow]
        let partnerID: String
        var ut = Utente()

        if msg.Mittente == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
            partnerID = msg.Destinatario!
        }
        else {
            partnerID = msg.Mittente!
        }

        print("PARTNER:\n",partnerID)
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Utenti").child(partnerID)

        //Retrieve the user
        ref.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            //print(snapshot)

            if let Diz = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

                let nome = Diz["Nome"] as? String
                let email = Diz["Email"] as? String
                let immProfilo = Diz["immProfilo"] as? String
                let UID = partnerID

                ut.nome = nome
                ut.email = email
                ut.immProfilo = immProfilo
                ut.ID = UID

                print("UT1:\n",ut)
            }
        }

        print("UT2:\n",ut)
        let chatsingola = segue.destination as! ChatSingola
        chatsingola.aaa = ut
    }
}
```

Comment: It's because the Firebase request runs asynchronously.  So you need to wait for the snapshot to be returned before setting the object in the destination view controller.  Alternatively, you could pass the partnerID to the destination view controller, and make the Firebase request once you are there.

Comment: If you want to wait for the response from firebase and after that perform the setting,  put the code inside the observer. ie., after ut.ID = UID, put let chatsingola = segue.destination as! ChatSingola
        chatsingola.aaa = ut.